# OpenJPA getSingleResult weirdness

Tags: openjpa

A have two entities: `Report` and `ReportSection` bound by `OneToMany` relation. Usually, each report contains more than one sections.

I use `OpenJPA 2.2.1` and recently I started encountering an error when trying to fetch specific `Report` while eagerly loading sections as well.

```
em.createNamedQuery("REPORT.findSingleWithSections").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
```

where `REPORT.findSingleWithSections` is:

```
SELECT r FROM Report r LEFT JOIN r.sections s WHERE r.id = :id;
```

**What I expect:** A single `Report` object to be fetched and all sections.

**What I get:** `NoUniqueResultException` exception

I am certain that querying is done via primary key, so there is **no** possibility for double records to actually exist in database.

If I change `getSingleResult` to `getResultList` I get one `(Report -> ReportSection)` for each pair which is, as far as I know, not correct behavior.

Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong here? Any hint would be helpful

Comment: I'm confused, you say that the query is done by primary key, but you say that there is a possibility for double records? For the id in question, how many rows are in the Report table?

Comment: I trust that when saying `SELECT r FROM Report r` that OpenJPA expects that each row is separate entity. So by having two `ReportSections` and using `JOIN` in your query you would get two, basically repeated, entites.

Comment: @Rick Sorry, my mistake, I meant "there is no possibility" :)

Comment: For giggles, what happens if you remove the `LEFT JOIN r.sections s` from your query? Do you still get the `NonUniqueResultException`?